# Juju services are not deploying correctly

Tags: juju, maas

> Deploying a charm to your MAAS Now you're ready for the most exciting
>   part: deploying a charm to your MAAS!
>
> juju deploy mysql MAAS will now allocate a node to Juju and Juju will
>   deploy the MySQL charm to that node. Again, it'll take a few minutes
>   to complete while Ubuntu installed and then the charm deploys.
>
> Let's have a quick status-check:
>
> juju status Once the charm is deployed, you'll see it reflected in the
>   environment's status.
>
> If you have another node free you can deploy WordPress and hook it up
>   to the MySQL service we just deployed:
>
> juju deploy wordpress juju add-relation wordpress mysql juju expose
>   wordpress juju status

From:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/Juju

And I get this:

```
hsf@ubuntuserwer:~$ juju status
2012-10-03 12:47:16,340 INFO Connecting to environment...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/hsf/.ssh/id_rsa':
2012-10-03 12:47:19,446 INFO Connected to environment.
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: ubuntuone
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-5ac593cc-0c76-11e2-a143-001185e67955/
    instance-state: unknown
  1:
    agent-state: not-started
    dns-name: node-001185e677fe.local
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-f108eb80-0d3a-11e2-ad9f-001185e67955/
    instance-state: unknown
  2:
    agent-state: not-started
    dns-name: node-001185e6772b.local
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-cc14c3c8-0d42-11e2-864b-001185e67955/
    instance-state: unknown
services:
  mysql:
    charm: cs:precise/mysql-8
    relations:
      db:
      - wordpress
    units:
      mysql/1:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 1
        public-address: null
  wordpress:
    charm: cs:precise/wordpress-9
    exposed: true
    relations:
      db:
      - mysql
      loadbalancer:
      - wordpress
    units:
      wordpress/1:
        agent-state: pending
        machine: 2
        open-ports: []
        public-address: null
2012-10-03 12:47:20,404 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
```

I tried several times and still is the same problem. Aget-state is saying that machines aren't started but they are.

What I am doing wrong?

Also when i run juju debug-log I get:

```
hsf@ubuntuserwer:~$ juju debug-log
2012-10-03 14:04:16,661 INFO Connecting to environment...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/hsf/.ssh/id_rsa':
2012-10-03 14:04:19,264 INFO Connected to environment.
2012-10-03 14:04:19,265 INFO Enabling distributed debug log.
2012-10-03 14:04:19,269 INFO Tailing logs - Ctrl-C to stop.
2012-10-03 13:56:03,513 Machine:0: juju.agents.machine INFO: Machine agent start                                                                                        ed id:0
2012-10-03 14:03:21,113 Machine:0: twisted ERROR: Unhandled error in Deferred:
2012-10-03 14:03:21,145 Machine:0: twisted ERROR: Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: zookeeper.NodeExistsException: node exists
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tha it's work! I again install ubuntu server and this time everything goes well but one thing.
Now when I juju status I see this:

```
2012-10-04 13:32:21,110 INFO Connected to environment.
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: node-00127968a7be.local
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-ab7c5eb6-0e08-11e2-bb37-001185e67955/
    instance-state: unknown
  1:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: node-001185e677fe
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-82beae92-0e09-11e2-a134-001185e67955/
    instance-state: unknown
  2:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: node-001185e6772b.local
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-5c21dc18-0e0a-11e2-a134-001185e67955/
    instance-state: unknown
services:
  mysql:
    charm: cs:precise/mysql-8
    relations:
      db:
      - wordpress
    units:
      mysql/0:
        agent-state: started
        machine: 1
        public-address: node-001185e677fe.localdomain
  wordpress:
    charm: cs:precise/wordpress-9
    exposed: true
    relations:
      db:
      - mysql
      loadbalancer:
      - wordpress
    units:
      wordpress/0:
        agent-state: started
        machine: 2
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        public-address: node-001185e6772b.local
```

public adress seems be strange because it's name of my nodes. I check on my router adress of node where is wordpress and type on webbrowser but I get

> 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.1.19

I don't know what to do. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure you have your gateway set up correctly?  1.1.19 isn't a valid IP address.